# Convert Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml into Executable

Tags: docker, electron, exe, executable

I am trying to package an Electron app that relies on several Docker containers into a single executable. I would like to be able to convert Dockerfile's into executables runnable on Windows. Is this possible? Can I pull this off without having Docker installed on the client machine? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.
Take into account, that docker images are packaged for certain architecture. Kernel must be compatible. And sure, you need docker engine to work on client machine. I think windows is not ready for this.

BRs